# Try Finally statement in F#

Tags: f#

I am new to learning F# and writing a simple console application, where the user enters a value for distance, and I want some validation to make sure that the input is a number. It also needs to make sure that it is a number, and if it isn't, tell the user and they start again. This is what I have so far:

```
        let distance = 0

        while distance = 0 do 
            System.Console.WriteLine("How far do you want to travel?")
            let answer = System.Console.ReadLine()

            try
                let distance = System.Int32.Parse(answer)

                if distance < 0 then
                    let distance = 0
                    printfn "Can't use negative numbers"
                elif distance = 0 then
                    printfn "Can't travel a distance of 0"
                else
                    printfn "You are about to travel %A" distance

            finally
                let distance = 0
                printfn "Invalid distance format"
```

And this is what comes up:

[image: ![Results of console app]

In this example, what I want to happen is for the "Invalid distance format" to **not** appear, and it moves on to the next part of the app.

How would I make it so that "Invalid distance format" only appears if `distance` can't be converted to an int via `System.Int32.Parse(answer)`

Even if try-finally is the complete wrong way to go about doing this, how else would it be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is `try...with`

```
   try
      let distance = System.Int32.Parse(answer)
      . . . . .

   with
   | _ as ex -> printfn "Invalid Distance Format"
```

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/

You could also do something like

```
...
let attemptedConvert =  Int32.TryParse(answer)
let success,convertValue = attemptedConvert
if success then 
  //other stuff here
else 
  printfn "Invalid Number Format"
```

This way there is no exception thrown, and you still have validation if the entry was converted successfully.

As noted below, exceptions can be a more expensive operation than other alternatives, and should be evaluated to see if that is causing unnecessary overhead.  Like any process though, this *should* be evaluated on a case by case basis.

[TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You should note that using Exceptions with F# are time expensive and that when one has a choice between using an exception or something else one should strongly consider the non-Exception version.

Comment: Too much code; terser and more idiomatic one-liner: `match Int32.TryParse answer with true,convertValue -> (* continue processing *) | _ -> printfn "Invalid Number Format"`

Comment: @GuyCoder I wholly agree with the sentiment but I think that clarity of intention is a far better reason that performance.  Given two functions `parseInt : string -> int` and `tryParseInt : string -> int option` the type system tells you the second function may fail when you write your code and that you need to handle that possible failure case.  The first function may just fail at runtime with no warning.  Exceptions are an exceptionally bad way of handling expected failures.

Answer (score 3):

As you are learning, I would approach this problem by doing something like this.

It makes use of the option type which is useful for handling the 'null' case (i.e. no input). It also uses F#s pattern matching, which is a very powerful alternative to using if, else, elif etc.

```
//see here - http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/
let tryParseOption intStr = 
   try
      let i = System.Int32.Parse intStr
      Some i
   with _ -> None

type Ask = 
static member Askdistance (?text)= 
        let text = defaultArg text "" 
        printfn "%s" text

        System.Console.WriteLine("How far do you want to travel?")
        let distance = tryParseOption (System.Console.ReadLine())

        match distance with 
            |None                  -> Ask.Askdistance("Invalid format distance provided")
            |Some(a) when a <0     -> Ask.Askdistance("Can't use negative numbers")
            |Some(a) when a =0     -> Ask.Askdistance("Can't travel a distance of 0")
            |_                     -> printfn "You are about to travel %A" distance.Value
        ignore()

//this will keep asking you to input a distance until you put in a correct value (i.e. a positive integer value. Note it will reject a floating point input). 
Ask.Askdistance()
```

Comment: hopefully you don't mind me posting another answer and 'attacking' yours. I see the benefit of your answer showing different ways of solving the same problem, it might be just a little bit over the top though :-)

Comment: Not at all! I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct, here is another way of doing it:

```
open System

let rec travel() =
    printfn "How far do you want to travel?"
    let d = Console.ReadLine()
    match Int32.TryParse d with
    | false, _ ->
        printfn "Invalid distance format '%s'" d
        travel()
    | _, 0 ->
        printfn "Can't travel a distance of 0"
        travel()
    | _, d when d < 0 ->
        printfn "Can't use negative number %i" d
        travel()
    | _, d ->
        printfn "You are about to travel %i" d

travel()
```

In my opinion, this has the following advantages:

- does not use exceptions
- does not use different concepts for the same thing (`printfn` vs `Console.WriteLine`)
- does not introduce unnecessary constructs (types, helper functions for already existing functionality)
- does not mix responsibilities (print error of this invocation in the next one)

I agree, that learning a new language you should explore the solution space. But then choose a concise, elegant way.

Some other aspects of my answer may be opinionated though. You might want to

- use explicit `true`s instead of `_`.
- choose a different name for the matched, parsed distance. I use shadowing because I think of the parsed value as just being a different representation.
- reorder the cases, e.g. having the 'happy path' first resembles a `try...catch`:

  ```
  open System

  let rec travel() =
      printfn "How far do you want to travel?"
      let d = Console.ReadLine()
      match Int32.TryParse d with
      | true, d when d > 0 ->
          printfn "You are about to travel %i" d
      | true, 0 ->
          printfn "Can't travel a distance of 0"
          travel()
      | true, _ ->
          printfn "Can't use negative number %i" d
          travel()
      | _ ->
          printfn "Invalid distance format '%s'" d
          travel()

  travel()
  ```

Another approach would be to *separate reading from the console and traveling*:

1. using a reading function which always returns an `int`:

   ```
   open System

   let rec readInt() =
       let d = Console.ReadLine()
       match Int32.TryParse d with
       | true, d ->
           d
       | _ ->
           printfn "Invalid distance format '%s'" d
           readInt()

   let rec travel() =
       printfn "How far do you want to travel?"
       let d = readInt()
       if d > 0 then
           printfn "You are about to travel %i" d
       elif d = 0 then
           printfn "Can't travel a distance of 0"
           travel()
       else
           printfn "Can't use negative number %i" d
           travel()

   travel()
   ```
2. using a reading function that might fail:

   ```
   open System

   let rec readInt() =
       let d = Console.ReadLine()
       match Int32.TryParse d with
       | true, d -> Some d
       | _ -> None

   let rec travel() =
       printfn "How far do you want to travel?"
       match readInt() with
       | Some d when d > 0 ->
           printfn "You are about to travel %i" d
       | Some d when d = 0 ->
           printfn "Can't travel a distance of 0"
           travel()
       | Some d ->
           printfn "Can't use negative number %i" d
           travel()
       | None ->
           printfn "Invalid distance format '%s'" d
           travel()

   travel()
   ```

Comment: A lot of your answer is good, I like that you've used a recursive function (over a method) and `printf` is superior to and more idiomatic than `Console.Write` in F# but I find the `Some<'T>` / `None` approach preferable to the `(bool, 'T)` tuple approach.  I think some combination of yours and @Pash101 's answer would be the best solution.